# What's the point of designing an application in an OOP way if an ORM is not used?

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, jpa, orm

Suppose there are specific classes in an appplication say 'Student' 'Location' 'City' etc.

```
class Student {
String name;
int age;
Location location;
}

class Location {
City city;
String country;
}

class City {
String cityName;
int cityCode;
}
```

This is just an example to show classes(Objects) containing references to other classes.

So now if an ORM(like hibernate) is used, this kind of data can be saved directly by:

```
save(student);
```

given that the object 'student' is defined properly(like it contains data).
Now this is easy and convenient.

But say we are not using ORM for some reasons, then

1.We get data from the client

2.Fill the objects with user's data(or something similar)(All of this happens in memory)

3.Now we again break down the data to save it to database(using SQL queries)
eg queries containing things like

1. student.location.city.cityName
2. student.location.city.cityCode etc

Now isn't this like doing the Object Oriented thing just for the sake of doing it.like...

1.Creating Objects in memory.

2.Breaking down objects prior to saving in database.

This thing has been confusing me for a long time. Any insights or help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried googling "advantages of OO design"?

Comment: I am talking wrt database stuff. Everyone knows that OO is great.I hope you got my point.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're trying to ask.  OO design in general has nothing to do with how your database access is coded.  The whole point of OO is that **how** you access the database is irrelevant to the rest of your program.  Even if you're using jdbc with hardcoded sql statements, you're still better off putting that code in a DAO.

Comment: I sounds like you're more interested in "Why should I use native SQL, rather than an ORM, with object oriented code". Does that sound accurate? If so, I would search for disadvantages and drawbacks of ORM tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your object-oriented programming language uses Objects.
2. Your database uses relational data.

Because of this mismatch, you will always have to map Objects to relational data, even if you don't choose to use an ORM tool.

You might be interested in the [Active-record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). Each row will have an associated Object reference, but you'll have to resolve Object associations by yourself (e.g. many-to-one, one-to-many).